# Integrating tumblr with ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, oauth, tumblr

I have been trying to integrate tumblr with my ios app for quite a long time now but its still not working. I am using oauth. It is logging me in but whenever I am clicking on allow it is crashing.
Can anyone please help?

Comment: showing some code and the crash message may help. Also, are you using some 3rd party frameworks for oauth and http requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved the issue....It was a stupid mistake..
Just needed to make the oauth viewcontroller arc enabled.